# Applying xaml style to button content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, datatemplate

Apologies if this is a stupid question. It seems like it should be easy but I just can't think of how to do it. I have a number of buttons, each of which will have an image and a text block for content. I'm trying to create a style for the buttons to set properties on the images and text blocks.

Here's what I've got so far.

In my view:

```
<Button Command="{Binding TolerancesCommand}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource DeviationIcon}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Tolerances"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

In my resource dictionary:

```
 <Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource NavButtonBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource NavButtonWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Green"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Specifically, I want set the image height and width in the style rather than having to set it individually on each button.

**Update**

Just to be clear, the style is getting applied ok. In the example above, the button text is green as set in the textblock foreground property. The problem is that I can't show the image. The button displays but its content is just text "System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel".

Comment: The source of the problem is clear (in spite of the fact that four different people made incorrect guesses about what the issue is): you are declaring a template that is intended to be applied to the content object of the `Button`, but you've made that content object a `<StackPanel/>` element instead of something that could be usefully bound to either `Image.Source` or `TextBlock.Text` (the latter being the element that gives you the type name of your `<StackPanel/>` object). Unfortunately, it's not clear what you _do_ want to happen. ...

Comment: ... Why you think it would even make sense to bind the same value to both of those properties (one expecting an `ImageSource` object and the other a `string` object) is not clear, and without the context a good [mcve] would provide, it's not possible to even make any reasonable inferences as to what behavior you really want.

Comment: do image have to be same for every Button

Comment: No, the point of the question is that I want to have a different image and different text for each button but to be able to give them a consistent style.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give the style a Key, and change the data template to a control template

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then on your button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding TolerancesCommand}">
...
</Button>
```

Also, be sure that your resource dictionary has been added to the application resources in the App.xaml class:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/FolderName/Dictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Binding` for the Image and TextBlock is what is causing your issue. Right now they are bound to the default value. You need to specify what you want those values to be bound to in order to get your desired results.

Here's some links

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf)

[WPF Tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/hello-bound-world/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need reusable style you can do as Bailey_989 suggest and if you want to apply custom content only for one button you can apply this code:

```
<Button Command="{Binding TolerancesCommand}">
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource DeviationIcon}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Tolerances"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

For image make sure that image is scaled. Best way would be that get .svg format image and convert it to .xaml after that just add it to your resources and use it. You will get vector image and you can scale it as large as you want and no pixels will be visible.